# Merging database tables using rank and path compression heuristics

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, merge, disjoint-sets

I am having trouble with the following problem in my data structures course. The errors provided by the course are rather ambiguous and I am not able to discern where the bug lies.

**NOTE:** The error message only says "Wrong answer." and the test cases are not provided.

**Input Format:** The first line of the input contains two integers  and  — the number of tables in the
database and the number of merge queries to perform, respectively.
The second line of the input contains  integers [] — the number of rows in the -th table.
Then the following  lines describe the merge queries. Each of them contains two integers n[i] and
[i] — the numbers of the tables to merge.

**Output Format:** For each query print a line containing a single integer — the maximum of the sizes of all
tables (in terms of the number of rows) after the corresponding operation.

**Sample Input:**

```
5 5
1 1 1 1 1
3 5
2 4
1 4
5 4
5 3
```

**Sample Output:**

```
2
2
3
5
5
```

This is my current code and it works for most cases but there seems to be some edge cases that I have not accounted for.

```py
class DataBases:
    def __init__(self, row_counts):
        self.max_row_count = max(row_counts)
        self.row_counts = row_counts
        n_tables = len(row_counts)
        self.parent = list(range(n_tables))
        self.rank = [1] * n_tables

    def get_parent(self, table):
        update_root = []
        root = table
        
        while root != self.parent[root]:
            update_root.append(self.parent[root])
            root = self.parent[root]
            
            for i in update_root:
                self.parent[i] = root
                
        return root

    def merge_tables(self, dst, src):
        src_parent = self.get_parent(src)
        dst_parent = self.get_parent(dst)
        if src_parent == dst_parent: return
        
        if self.rank[src_parent] > self.rank[dst_parent]:
            self.parent[dst_parent] = src_parent
            self.update_row_counts(src_parent, dst_parent)
        else:
            self.parent[src_parent] = dst_parent
            self.update_row_counts(dst_parent, src_parent)
            if self.rank[src_parent] == self.rank[dst_parent]:
                self.rank[dst_parent] += 1
    
    def update_row_counts(self, root, child):
        self.row_counts[root] += self.row_counts[child]
        self.row_counts[child] = 0
        self.max_row_count = max(self.max_row_count, self.row_counts[root])

def main():
    n_tables, n_queries = map(int, input().split())
    counts = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert(n_tables == len(counts))
    db = DataBases(counts)
    for i in range(n_queries):
        dst, src = map(int, input().split())
        db.merge_tables(dst - 1, src - 1)
        print(db.max_row_count)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the get_parent (path compression) implementation.

**Correct Solution:**

```py
    def get_parent(self, table):
        
        if table != self.parent[table]:
            self.parent[table] = self.get_parent(self.parent[table])
                
        return self.parent[table]
```